# Include datatable in existing linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below piece of code which gives my time zones as per each country

```
var zones = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default
                                  .ZoneLocations
                                  .Where(x => x.CountryCode == countryCode)
                                  .Select(x => x.ZoneId);
```

Now i need to include datatable within the above linq query to check if that datatable have the zone locations in database already as explained in below code. How do i do that ?

```
var zones = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default
                                  .ZoneLocations
                                  .Where(x => x.CountryCode == countryCode && 
            oratznamesoratznames.Select().ToList()
            .Exists(row => row["TZNAME"].ToString().ToUpper() == x.ZoneId))
                                  .Select(x => x.ZoneId);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question; what is wrong with the lower statement? Does it yield an error?

Comment: What is your final idea: do you need to get all the zones that also exist in your datatable (which name is ?? And the column name to check is ??)?

Comment: the first code gives me list of time zones for a specific country but few of the zone locations doesnt work in oracle so with second statement i intend to filter time zones those which are supported by oracle but its not filtering it properly i need to find out zone locations which are supported in both the first linq query filtered by country and some how include the datatabe in the same linq just to validate if the datatable which contains all time zones supported by oracle is there

Answer (score 0):

Id I understand your question correcty, you could use `.Any()`. It returns a boolean indicating where any of the elements of the collection matches the predicate.

Also, note that there is no need to use `&&` in this case.

```
var zones = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default
                              .ZoneLocations
                              .Where(x => x.CountryCode == countryCode)
                              .Select(x => x.ZoneId)
                              .Where(x => oratznamesoratznames
                                  .Any(r => r["TZNAME"].ToString().ToUpper() == x))
```

Comment: sorry but it didnt filtered its still showing time zones which is not in oracle

Comment: Divide and conquer. Check the contents of `oratznamesoratznames`. Are you sure `["TZNAME"].ToUpper()` and `ZoneId`s are comparable? I don't see anything wrong with the query